# Try to close SDL_CloseAudio has deadlock when RTSP server is down

Tags: ffmpeg, sdl, live555

I try to using live555(a.k.a OpenRTSP) to setup RTSP server and client. 
 
My Client application using live555, ffmpeg and SDL as streaming, decode and playback.

I found it might have deadlock if I try to call *SDL_CloseAudio* as following situation:

- When RTSP is down.
- When network is broken.

I am exclude it related to any timing issue because it works well if I try to call *SDL_CloseAudio* when server is not down.

Also, I have tried following API but still not work:

- Try *SDL_PauseAudio* before close it.
- Try *SDL_UnlockAudio* before close it.

Any idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

After I trace the SDL source code, I found it may related to mutex when SDL still under process *SDL_RunAudio*

Also, according my situation it will works well if the network still work (or server not down). So I try to send a kilo-byte fake audio data with "0" before close it.

```
    PacketQueue             m_audioq; //working queue.

    AVPacket *pktAudio = NULL;
    uint8_t data[1024] = {0};
    pktAudio = (AVPacket*)av_malloc(sizeof(AVPacket));
    av_init_packet(pktAudio);
    pktAudio->data = data;
    pktAudio->size = 1024;
    packet_queue_put(&m_audioq, pktAudio);

    SDL_CloseAudio();
```